# Open new BarChart Window (JavaFX) from inside a Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, window, javafx, bar-chart

How can I open a new bar chart window (JavaFX) when I am clicking on a button (inside a swing jar-application)?

I have already a functioning GUI with a button handler, but I can't connect the example from Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm) with the button so that the bar chart opens when I click the button.

I am working with the desktop Java Development Kit (Version 7 Update 40, 64-bit) and Eclipse Juno.

Basically I tried this:

```
...
BarChartSample chart = new BarChartSample();
Stage stage = new Stage();
chart.start(stage);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it with your window made in swing (the one containing the chart).

If you do that the code would look something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chart");
final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(fxPanel);
```

and after that you should add the chart to the fxPanel, since javaFx is thread safe you will have to use the Platform.runLater:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      BarChartSample chart = new BarChartSample();
      fxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));
   }
});
```

Hope it helps!

---

Edit:

The chart should something like this:

```
BarChart<String, Number> chart = getChart();
```

The previous line of code should be in a:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         //CODE HERE
       }
    });
```

Again, this is cause javaFx is thread safe.

and the method to create it:

```
public BarChart<String, Number> getChart() {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String, Number> bc = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,
                yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 41941.19));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 18722.18));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        return bc;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I took exactly the first example from the link I posted above and put it into `BarChartSample.java`. But the problem with your code is that `new Scene(chart)` is not applicable for the argument from type `BarChartSample`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The chart should be of class node, and not application. Careful there.
So actually what you should add instead of chart to the Scene is "bc", from that example.

Comment: I edited the original answer, so that you can see what you should be adding as the chart.